# Terraform kubernetes secret with .p12 file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I have to create a secret using .p12 keystore (binary file). If I am creating it as below-

```
resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "app_keystore" {
  metadata {
    name = "app-keystore"
    namespace = "test"
  }
  type = "Opaque"
  data = {
   "test.p12"=file("./secret/appkeystore/test.p12")
  }
}
```

It is giving below error

[image]

With filebase64 encoding, no error but the .p12 is encoded twice.

Comment: "giving errors" - what errors? You have to be very precise on what is wrong with your code. Your current question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: I have reframed the question.

Comment: With the same file without any encoding, the secret is working fine when I am directly creating it in the k8s namespace.

Comment: Is `test.p12` supposed to be a text file?

Comment: it is a binary file comprising jwt and saml keys.

Answer (score 0):

Found the resolution.

```
binary_data = {
    "test.p12"=filebase64("./secret/appkeystore/test.p12")
  }
```

The correct encoding for a binary file is **filebase64**.